# how can I generate aggregate pmd report via maven in command line?

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm working on multi-module maven project. I tried the following command, but it's not working

```
mvn pmd:pmd -Dpmd.aggregate=true
```

`pmd` generates report in a target directory of each module, but not in an unique one.

How can I generate an unique report for this project?

Comment: Which version of maven-pmd-plugin do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `aggregate` property is available [since](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html) version `2.2`.

Moreover, there is no `pmd.aggregate` property, the user property is simply `aggregate`, hence you should invoke

```
mvn pmd:pmd -Daggregate=true
```

And not

```
mvn pmd:pmd -Dpmd.aggregate=true
```